# Scala: why Float.floatToIntBits(2f) fails?

Tags: scala

```
scala> Float.floatToI
```

On pressing tab here, it displays `Float.floatToIntBits`. But,

```
scala> Float.floatToIntBits(2f)
<console>:6: error: value floatToIntBits is not a member of object Float
       Float.floatToIntBits(2f)
             ^
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Float.floatToIntBits` tries to call method on the object [`scala.runtime.Float`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/runtime/Float$.html) (I think).

```
scala> Float
res2: Float.type = object scala.Float
```

You need `java.lang.Float.floatToIntBits`:

```
scala> java.lang.Float.floatToIntBits(2f)
res1: Int = 1073741824
```

Comment: Thanks. It works. curious to know why the method is displayed on available list of members while pressing tab in REPL?

Comment: There are some spurious things in the REPL auto-completion ... they are just bugs which will be fixed.

Answer (score 4):

The REPL code-completion shows methods from all the `Float` objects available on the path (i.e.<strike>`scala.Float`</strike> `scala.runtime.Float` and `java.lang.Float`). However <strike>`scala.Float`</strike> `scala.runtime.Float` takes precedence over `java.lang.Float` and hence the error.

The following works:

```
scala> import java.lang.{Float => JFloat}
import java.lang.{Float=>JFloat}

scala> JFloat.floatToIntBits(2f)
res5: Int = 1073741824
```

Comment: Is the object `scala.Float` actually defined anywhere? Searching for `float` at the API site only gives `scala.runtime.Float`, nor is there a definition in `package.scala` or `Predef.scala`...

Comment: @Alexey: It seems they moved `Float` from `scala` to `scala.runtime` in v2.8.

Comment: @Alexey: I think `scala.Float` is now defined as an alias to `scala.runtime.Float` in the `scala` package object. http://paste.pocoo.org/show/253212/

Comment: Well, http://lampsvn.epfl.ch/trac/scala/browser/scala/tags/R_2_8_0_final/src/library/scala/package.scala doesn't seem to have it.

Comment: @Alexey: The first line in the scaladoc of scala.runtime.Float(Link: scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/runtime/Float$.html) reads "A object representing object scala.Float." Not sure what that means. :(

Comment: @Alexey: I don't know for sure but I think it's like this: Neither the `scala.runtime.Float` object nor its alias in `scala` package object actually exist; They are just compiler magic.

Comment: `scala.runtime.Float` _is_ defined in http://lampsvn.epfl.ch/trac/scala/browser/scala/tags/R_2_8_0_final/src//library/scala/runtime/AnyValCompanion.scala#L77 but "compiler magic" does seem likely for `scala.Float`.

Comment: wish Scala REPL lists only the methods on the object which has 'precedence' because it seemed so obvious to work but the listed method resulting in error :(

Comment: @Alexey: But the alias would be trivial to define: `val Float = scala.runtime.Float`. Why won't they define it then?

Comment: The following changeset seems to be related to the compiler magic: https://lampsvn.epfl.ch/trac/scala/changeset/21408 . 
I have neither found a reference in the specification nor the corresponding ticket, but I haven't searched very thoroughly.